# Razor directive to prevent element rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I search for an option to render some div-tags in my cshtml files with razor conditionally like the angular directive ng-if.
Normally I write code like

```cs
@if (mycond) {
  <div>blub</div>
}
```

And I search for a more readable approach like

```cs
  <div asmarttag:mycond>blub</div>
```

Is there any option to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's exactly what you want... but what about a custom HTMLHelper?

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class CustomHTMLHelpers
    {
        public static IHtmlString Render(this HtmlHelper helper, bool render, string html)
        {

            if (render)
            {
                return helper.Raw(html);
            }
            else
            {
                return new HtmlString("");
            }

        }

    public static IHtmlString Render(this HtmlHelper helper, bool render, MvcHtmlString html)
    {

        if (render)
        {
            return html;
        }
        else
        {
            return new HtmlString("");
        }

    }

}
```

Then you could do:

```
@Html.Render(mycond, "<div>blub</div>")
```

or

```
@Html.Render(true, @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home"))
```

Would certinly turn it into a one liner for you.

Comment: Hello, This looks like a smart idea! But for simple strings, I lose the HTML code completion and razor code can't be included in such text.

Comment: If you want html code completion then I think the if statement you are using will be the only way to achieve that.

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Comment: Just updated my answer. The additional method may cover the razor code part...?